# ¿como imprimir una linea especifica de un documento con FGETS?

Tags: php, fgets

Con FGETS puedo imprimir todo el contenido de un documento de texto en la web, pero no consigo imprimir solo una linea, por ejemplo la numero 3. ¿Se puede hacer esto con este metodo o se requiere de otro?

intente lo siguiente, pero solo me imprime letra por letra de la linea uno:

```
$pru = fopen( 'prueba.php', 'r' );
while ( $G = fgets( $pru ) ) {
echo $G[0] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar [file()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file.php)

```
$pru = file( 'prueba.php' ); // Lo convierte en un array
echo $pru[2]; // Tercera linea
```

Comment: he leido que esto consume muchos recursos ¿sabes algo de eso?.pero si, es genial, muy facil, muy directo

Comment: Según... si se hace muchas peticiones al archivo podría petarlo... pero dudo que llegues a ese punto y si llegas... tendrías quizás que optimizar muchas cosas más

Answer (score 0):

Hay un mejor método para hacer esto. Puedes echar mano de la clase **[`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.splfileobject.php)** e ir directamente a la línea del fichero que te interesa sin tener que recorrerlo línea por línea.

Para hacerlo más fácil podemos crear una función.

El código sería:

#### Función

Que llamarás cada vez que quieras el dato que haya en `$theLine` del archivo `$theFile`:

```
function readFileByLine($theFile, $theLine){
    /*Conviene establecer controles de la existencia del archivo*/

    $file = new SplFileObject($theFile);
    $file->seek($theLine);
    return $file->current();            
}
```

#### Modo de uso

```
$theFile="prueba.php";
$theLine=3;
echo readFileByLine($theFile, $theLine);
```

#### Ventajas

Este método tiene tres ventajas esencialmente:

- No hay que recorrer todo el archivo línea por línea
- No hay que volcar todo el archivo en una variable cuando sólo necesitas una línea
- Se hace uso de la potencia de los objetos para mover el puntero a una determinada línea del fichero con `seek` y se obtiene el dato de la línea con `current`

Comment: gracias pero no uso la sintaxis orientada a objetos...me confundo

Comment: Lalo, ¿por qué no la usas? ¿es un curso y no puedes usarla? Si es para programas de la vida real no hay nada que te impida aprenderla, además es más intuitiva, más clara y las clases (y los objetos) tienen muchas más facilidades y potencialidades como las que explico y otras. Si quieres puedes usar `file`, como te sugiere @aldanux, es también una respuesta válida, pero has de saber que estás trayendo a memoria todo un archivo para luego sacar una sola línea de él. Si el archivo tiene 5 líneas ok, pero si son miles y es un proceso concurrente, la diferencia de rendimiento se notará.

Comment: No la uso porque me da flojera aprender una nueva sintaxis... mucho tiempo estudiando php para que venga una actualizacion que me diga que debo aprender una nueva sintaxis y olvidarme de lo anterior aprendido. Pero para base de datos si la uso. Es facil.

Comment: @lalo2019 es una muy mala actitud con la que entiendes el aprender POO, ya que no es exclusivo de PHP y eso es un indicio muy malo de tu desempeño pues muestra tu resistencia a ser autodidacta, una característica necesaria para sobre salir en este mundo del desarrollo de software, como Docente te lo digo replantea tu actitud, no puedes esperar lograr o aprender mucho si tu única excusa es "flojera"

Comment: @lalo2019 aquí hablamos de algo mucho más importante, no es sólo de sintaxis. Mi propuesta es hacer uso de una característica de PHP con una potencialidad considerable. Hablamos de que no tienes que leer todo un archivo para sacar una ínfima fila que está dentro de él. Si el lenguaje ofrece esa posibilidad no puedes argumentar que no la usas porque te da *flojera*. En cualquier caso eres libre de implementar la tecnología que quieras, pero en programación no es cuestión de gustos, sino de objetividad, de rendimiento y optimización del código. Aunque esto te ahorre sólo medio segundo ...

Comment: ... en un contexto, y en otro te ahorre un minuto. Y así tengas miles de optimizaciones que te ahorren un segundo cada una, son ya 1000 segundos. Si multiplicamos eso por 10,542 usuarios conectados al mismo tiempo en ese proceso, cada uno lanzando un bucle de 40 iteracciones. Si le echas lápiz a todo eso podemos estar hablando de horas ganadas en optimización en un código que parecía una cosa de nada. Es así como yo entiendo la *optimización*.

Comment: en la pagina dice que es mas segura y recomendada pero no es indispensable, es decir es simplemente una opcion personal usarla o no. Incluso te escriben todos los ejemplos en dos sintaxis. Pero si, tal vez deba aprenderla, no me cierro, pero por ahora no creo. Tampoco creo que sea tan dificil porque por ejemplo cuando me enseñaste de POO para base de datos (si, tu me respondiste el mensaje y me recomendaste esa sintaxis) la aprendi en minutos..pero una cosa es eso y otra trasladar todo lo que he aprendido a la POO.

Comment: @lalo2019 realmente no quiero convencerte de nada, sólo decir que cuando se trata de *optimización* del código los gustos no entran. Si hay algo más óptimo, aunque no te guste, es lo que deberías implementar. Hacer lo contrario sería como si tuvieras que seleccionar un trabajador entre 1000 que viven en Australia. La selección se puede hacer de dos maneras: a) Viajas a Australia, seleccionas el trabajador in situ y lo traes a trabajar a la empresa; b) Le pagas el billete de avión a los 1000, seleccionas uno para que se quede a trabajar y le pagas el billete de vuelta a los 999.

Comment: ... he exagerado un poco los números, pero es lo que ocurre si el archivo tuviera mil filas. Y si tiene 7,500 filas, pues eso, le estás pagando billete de ida a 7,500 personas y billete de vuelta a 7,499. Si haces eso miles de veces es muy probable que la empresa no resista (`out of memory!`). Es así como yo entiendo la optimización, no es una cosa banal. Si tienes que optimizar hazlo, así el archivo tenga 4 filas. ¿Qué te asegura que mañana  ese archivo no va a crecer?

Comment: SplFileObject no es una mágia... es simplemente una clase... con varios métodos... Mira el método [seek()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.3.1/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc#L367) y me dirás si lee solo una linea como tu dices...

Comment: @aldanux no he dicho que sea una magia y en mi respuesta hay un enlace `SplFileObject` donde se ve perfectamente que es una clase. Ahora bien, no hace lo que hace `file` que: ***Transfiere un fichero completo a un array***. El uso de `SplFileObject`  te permite moverte dentro del fichero y obtener el dato que necesitas.

Comment: @aldanux [te dejo esto](http://blog.gordon-oheim.biz/2011-05-16-Iterating-File-Contents-With-SPL/) si quieres conocer algunas ventajas más de `SplFileObject`.